# How to get previous month name and year using format() or any way in vb script?

Tags: vbscript

How to get previous month name and year using format() or any way possible in vb script?

Ex: if current month = february, i want output = January2014
 if current month = january 2014, i want output = December 2013

Kindly help.

Answer (score 5):

All of the previous answers were for VB.NET. If you want a VBScript solution, try this:

```
' Here's how you can get the starting and ending days of the previous month...
dtEnding   = Date - Day(Date)
dtStarting = dtEnding - Day(dtEnding) + 1

' To display the month and year...
MsgBox MonthName(Month(dtEnding)) & " " & Year(dtEnding)
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way I can find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this example.

```
Dim dateGiven As DateTime = Date.Now
dateGiven = dateGiven.AddMonths(-1)

MsgBox(dateGiven.ToString("Y"))
```

if you want to remove the comma, do this

```
Dim dateGiven As DateTime = Date.Now
Dim output As String = ""
dateGiven = dateGiven.AddMonths(-1)

output = dateGiven.ToString("Y")

output = output.Replace(",", "")
MsgBox(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

In VB.Net you can use .AddMonth(-1):

`Dim newDate as DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1)`

use .ToString() with a format supplier to return it in the correct format:

`Console.WriteLine(newDate.ToString("MMMM yyyy"))`

In VBScript you can use the DateAdd function:

`Dim newDate : newDate = DateAdd("m", -1, now)`

And use a stringbuilder to format it right

`wscript.echo CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder").AppendFormat("{0:MMMM yyyy}", newDate).ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox(Now.AddMonths(-1).ToString("Y"))
```